# javascript Date parse separators?

Tags: javascript

http://jsbin.com/izupek/edit#javascript,html

all 3 examples are `working` and parsing my date.

Ive read in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

that

RFC822  pattern is ok to parse

subset of ISO 8601  pattern is ok to parse

but none of them talks about the **separators** between  dd mm ....

where can I find official info about the separators ?

Comment: The third string is invalid in Firefox.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas still , where is the definition

Comment: You mean, where is it defined which formats of date-strings are valid?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas where is the documuntation about the **separators** !

Comment: Well, aren't the separators defined by the date format? For instance, the format `mm/dd/yyyy` defines that the separator is `/`, and so on. Therefore, if you'd like to know which separators are valid, you have to look up which date-formats are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found those two links on MDN:

- [World Wide Web Consortium Note on ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)
- [Commentary by one Markus Kuhn](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html)

The second document explicitely states:

> > The international standard date notation is
> >
> > **YYYY-MM-DD**
> >
> > where YYYY is the year in the usual Gregorian calendar, MM is the month of the year between 01 (January) and 12 (December), and DD is the day of the month between 01 and 31.
> >
> > For example, the fourth day of February in the year 1995 is written in the standard notation as
> >
> > **1995-02-04**

Judging from that, the *dash* (`-`) character is the standard separator.